# Owl Carousel Auto Play for screen

Tags: jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I am using Owl carousel as a jquery slider, I want to design my design responsive, When I want to run according to screen sizes, should I add scripts for each screen size?

Can you help me?

Do you think I should use owl carousel for responsive slider?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
      items: 20,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 1000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
      responsiveClass: true,
      nav: true,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
        600: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
        1000: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
      },
    });
    $('.play').on('click', function () {
      owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
    });
    $('.stop').on('click', function () {
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want diferent settings for autoplay? If yes, set as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
      items: 20,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 1000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
      responsiveClass: true,
      nav: true,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          autoplay: false, //disable autoplay to screen from 0 to 600px
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
        600: {
          autoplay: true, //enable autoplay to screen from 0 to 600px
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
        1000: {
          autoplay: false, //disable autoplay to screen from 1000px and more
          items: 1,
          nav: false,
          loop: true,
        },
      },
    });
    $('.play').on('click', function () {
      owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);
    });
    $('.stop').on('click', function () {
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    });
  });
```